# Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `id` in Prisma

Tags: mysql, prisma

```
model Renting_Units {
  id              Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
  name            String            @unique(map: "name") @db.VarChar(255)
  description     String?           @db.VarChar(255)
  createdAt       DateTime          @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  updatedAt       DateTime          @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  User            Users             @relation(fields: [id], references: [id])
  created_by      Int
  Renting_Periods Renting_Periods[]
}


model Renting_Periods {
  id            Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  product_id    Int           @db.Int
  Products      Products      @relation(fields: [product_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  start_date    DateTime      @db.DateTime(0)
  end_date      DateTime      @db.DateTime(0)
  createdAt     DateTime      @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  updatedAt     DateTime      @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  renting_unit  Int           @db.Int
  Renting_Units Renting_Units @relation(fields: [renting_unit], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  User          Users         @relation(fields: [id], references: [id])
  created_by    Int
  Invoices      Invoices[]
}
```

I am getting an error with foreign key ID.
I have added some renting periods, after I created some more I got this error, but the ID is autoincrement.
I tried different things from online but I did not find a solution.
The problem is that it happend also once, but I have refreshed the database and after sometime it happened again.

Code where I am trying to insert a new renting Period:

```
  await prisma.renting_Periods.create({
      data: {
        Products: {
          connect: {
            id: product_id,
          },
        },
        start_date,
        end_date,
        Renting_Units: {
          connect: {
            id: renting_unit_id,
          },
        },
        created_by: user_data.id,
      },
    });



The full erorr that displayed on the console:



→  74 await prisma.renting_Periods.create(
  Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `id`
    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError 
  clientVersion: '4.2.1',
  meta: { field_name: 'id' }
```

Comment: There should be more to the error, can you post the full error exactly as it appears?

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky I have just updated the error code and also inserted the insert function I am using

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect either a `Product` or `Renting_Units` model to a `renting_Periods` model, but the ID you are referencing does not refer to a `Product` or `Renting_Units` model. The ID might refer to something else, but the error is generated when you're using an ID that is not valid for the operation you are trying to perform (in this case connecting `Product` or `Renting_Units`).

Comment: The ID are correct regarding the product_id and renting_unit_id, can you give a code snippet how this can be done?

Comment: It's not a code thing, it's a database thing. Do you know for a _fact_ that the IDs you are using refer to existing models? Try using Prisma Studio to confirm what the IDs are supposed to be: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-studio